# How to read embedded excel in excel and store the information in the embedded file in the master excel file?

Tags: python, r, excel, vba

I have an excel file that contains a column named "Workers Details", which has another excel file embedded into the cell in it.

[A snipshot of the excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fbJ6.png)

I have >500 rows of companies each with an embedded excel file under "Workers Details". **How can I access the embedded excel and store its contents into the master excel file as shown below?** Any help will be much appreciated!

[How I want to store the embedded file inside the master file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obYz8.png)

Comment: I think excel sheets are solution for this. you can use excel sheets for this.

Comment: you an use links for internal sheets instead of external file.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I'm already given the excel file with embedded excel files and I had to manually copy and paste the contents in the embedded excel files into the master file. Is there a faster way to read and store inside the excel file?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something around this

```
Sub GET_EXCEL()

Dim o As OLEObject
Dim e As Excel.Workbook

Set o = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(1)
Set e = o.Object

Debug.Print e.Sheets(1).Range("e10").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! Which programming tool do you use?

Comment: I used VBA as it was in the tags.